# How to style a specific cell of col in css

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table with 5 top level cols and each top level colum spans 4 cols.
I want to apply a different style to the last child-column of each top level column.
How should that be done.

```html
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='3'> First </th>
      <th colspan='2'> Second </th>
      <th> Third </th>
      <th> Fourth </th>
      <th> Fifth </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
    <colgroup>
       <col span=3>
       <col span=2>
       <col>
       <col>
       <col>
    </colgroup>

   <tr>
<!-- First col -->
     <td> data </td>
     <td> data </td>
     <td> this one </td>

<!-- Second col -->
     <td> data </td>
     <td> this one </td>

<!-- Remain cols -->
     <td> data </td>
     <td> data </td>
     <td> data </td>
   </tr>
   </tobdy>
</table>
```

I want to have same background for each `col` but I also want to have the last element of each col to be different in background. So the last element of each col should have green background for say.

[image: A sample table]

Trying to come up with a valid selector to style the desired column

Comment: *"I have a table with 5 top level cols and each top level colum spans 4 cols"* - So 20 `td` in each row? - Your code does not show this layout description.

Comment: But *from the description* you just want every 4th element in each row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the selector you are looking for is `td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(5)` – see snippet below. If not, please provide a better description of what you are looking for.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #ddd;
}

td:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(5) {
  background: #fc9;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='3'> First </th>
      <th colspan='2'> Second </th>
      <th> Third </th>
      <th> Fourth </th>
      <th> Fifth </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <colgroup>
      <col span=3>
      <col span=2>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
      <td> data </td>
      <td> data </td>
      <td> data #this one</td>

      <td> data </td>
      <td> data #this one</td>

      <td> data </td>
      <td> data </td>
      <td> data </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You may use :nth-last-child also. For more information https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/